# Converting integer values to string in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, wso2, xslt-1.0, wso2-esb

I have an element in my XSLT named profileid. The value to this element can be expected as a set of numbers that is right now going as integer(eg. 452628), but this value has to be passed as a string to the next process. Is there a way I can convert this integer value to string within xslt itself? [I am using XSLT 1.0]

XSLT I've used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output indent="no" method="xml"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
              <Session>
                <xsl:variable name="profileID" select="concat(' ',$profileid)"/>
                <profileId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate($profileID,' ','')"/>
                </profileId>
            </Session>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Converted the xml response to json)

JSON output :-

`{ "Session": { "profileId": 452628 } }`

Expected JSON output:_

`{ "Session": { "profileId": "452628" } }`

A way to convert this integer value to String inside xslt

Comment: The XSLT you have posted outputs an XML structure, but then you refer to some JSON output?

Comment: What version of WSO2 product do you have? And for that simple case maybe is better to use `payload factory` ?

Comment: I am iterating through multiple records and xslt seemed the best fit for it. once the xml output is generated i am setting the messageType as application/json to convert it into a json output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want all the attributes as String values. After the XSLT transformation set the following property using [JSON Transform Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/JSON+Transform+Mediator)

```xml
<jsontransform>
    <property name="synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive" value = "false"/>
</jsontransform>
```